# Magento checkout - remove "Subtotal" and the "Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed)"

Tags: magento

In Magento checkout page (/checkout/onepage/)

I want to remove "Subtotal" and the "Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed)" (I have always free shipping) lines and let only "Grand Total" with 2 other text lines under it.

How can I do that ?

Please help, I have tried 2 days !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the base template files set: app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\reviews\totals.phtml find the line

`echo $this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan);`

and remove this, and you should lose the subtotal and shipping & handling details from the onepage checkout review section.

I'm working with version 1.5.1.0

Comment: Please never do this in the base template files. At the very least, copy this file to your theme folder - i.e. `app\design\frontend\<yourpackage>\<yourtheme>\template\checkout\onepage\reviews\totals.phtml` :)

Answer (score 3):

To remove the "Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed)" and only use the Free Shipping go to admin panel -> System-> Configuration -> Shipping Methods http://grab.by/amji

here you can disable the flat rate shipping and enable only the free shipping one.

As for the Subtotal ... if you are charging tax on your website it would be very unprofessional not to show a sub total ... but if you insist on removing it you will have to handle it with some changes at template level.

Comment: Thanks for help, I have used the "Free Shipping" but I don't want to show it as a shipping method. 

All my prices are without tax (it's only a B2B shop)

Thanks.

Comment: So you kinda want to skip the shipping part during checkout right?

Comment: yes, and also to add custom 2 lines text under "Grans Total" :)

Comment: It would require to hack some OTB standard functionality. Are you familiar with controller and model rewrites?

Comment: Yes, I have already done similar things before, but I don't know exactly how to do that... which files should I rewrite...

Comment: You need to look at the OnepageController located at \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php ... in there you have two actions saveBillingAction and saveShippingAction in each of these there is $result['goto_section'] ... the value in there indicates the section the user should be sent two after processing the shipping/billing address. You have to modify it to send him directly to the payment section ... but also you have to manually add the free shipping type to the quote after adding the shipping address. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

little late, but can be useful to someone else.
If you want to hide (disable) shipping options when delivery is free, you can check this extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/12210/
OR
http://magento.modulabs.com/mage_en/magento-hide-all-shipping-when-free-shiping-enabled.html