# Remove "sub total" from magento shopping cart

Tags: magento

I'm running Magento 1.7.0.0 and somehow have 2 instances of "sub total" in the cart before checkout. How do I remove one of them or which file should I edit??????

 Thanx!!

[image: my cart]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot ... Take a look @ /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/cart/*

Comment: Checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354599/magento-checkout-remove-subtotal-and-the-shipping-handling-flat-rate-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is due to an extension.  Start disabling extensions in /app/etc/modules/ (that don't begin with Mage for example) until you find the culprit.